# Finding closure of a set in Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Euclidean Space $R^2$,
A : {(x,y) ∈ $Q^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1$ }.
I'm trying to prove that the closure of A is $\overline A$ : {(x,y) ∈ $R^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ }.
In other words I have to prove that any nbd of any point in $\overline A$ contains a point in A. Any help?

Comment: What defintion of a closed set can you use?

Comment: A is not closed, can u elaborate? thanks

Comment: Notice that if $x$ is in $A$, clearly any neighborhood of $A$ contains a point in $A$. Now what happens if you're on the boundary? Take a point $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. What does a neighborhood of $(x,y)$ look like? Does it contain a point in $A$?

Comment: @Saegusa , well first you have to take another thing into account, if x is not on the boundary and is not in A, Secondly i know how it looks like, and well aware of the geometric interpretation. but i can't seem to right an exact proof.

Comment: You might want to use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the sequential characterization of closure for subsets of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^2, r > 0$, set $B(x, r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lVert y - x \rVert < r\}$, the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ to prove that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $\overline{\mathbb{Q}^2} = \mathbb{R}^2$. Also prove that $\overline{B(0, 1)} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lVert x \rVert \leq 1\}$ (this is true in any normed vector space, not just $\mathbb{R}^2$).

You want to show that $\overline{B(0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^2} = \overline{B(0, 1)}$. It suffices to show that $\overline{B(0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}^2} \supset B(0, 1)$. But this is easy to show using the density of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: i don't understand what B(0,1) stands for

Comment: @mehrdad I added the definition.

Comment: thank you Mason for the edit, but i still seem to lack some clarity,since i'm new to analysis. i proved it using density of Q in R. i think i should be deleting my post.